# Rewrite a file in use in java

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I play at Minecraft (famous Java Games), I want to rewrite the jar file that Minecraft is using (replace the 1.7.10-OptiFine_HD_U_D6.jar by an other 1.7.10-OptiFine_HD_U_D6.jar) when Minecraft is running and whitout closing Minecraft
I test this code, but the file will not be delete because Minecraft is using it.
https://hastebin.com/iwuxiyokuy.cpp (I  put this code in the code of Minecraft, I thought that if Minecraft is sleeping, it will not be considered like a file in use)
But, I tried some ideas and I found this:
In Eclipse you can rewrite the 1.7.10-OptiFine_HD_U_D6.jar without closing Minecraft
(Like this http://hpics.li/4971e5f)

So, how can I rewrite, in java, 1.7.10-OptiFine_HD_U_D6.jar like Eclipse when Minecraft is running and without closing Minecraft ?

Have a nice day !

(Sorry for my bad english I'm young and I'm French :/)

Comment: Even if you were able to modify the file, it wouldn't do what you want.  When the game is running, many of its classes have already been loaded from the JAR file.  Changing classes in the JAR won't change the code that the game has already loaded into RAM.

Comment: That's what I want :) (= to change the JAR after Minecraft has loaded it, whitout applying the changes of the new jar and without loaded Minecraft again) So how can I do this ? (without using Eclipse)

Comment: You can't be sure that the changes *won't* be applied, either.  Java loads classes only when they're needed, so the game will have loaded some classes but not (yet) all of them.  If you replace the JAR, when the game needs more classes later, it'll load the new versions.  You'll end up using a mixture of old and new classes, which is likely to cause a crash.

Comment: Anyway, what's the point of replacing the JAR file if you don't want the game to actually *use* the new version?

Comment: It's for a joke/troll

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your operating system (Windows in this case) locks the file because it is being used by Minecraft (Java).
**There is nothing you can do in Java to work around this limitation.**

The dialog that says that the file already exists is simply a warning by Eclipse so you don't overwrite an already existing/the wrong file by accident; it has nothing to do with the operating system locking the file.

Out of curiosity, why do you want to replace the file while Minecraft is running? Why not close Minecraft, replace the file and start Minecraft again?
I highly doubt that Minecraft will load the file after it has been loaded at startup.

**edit 1**:
This should do:

```
File source = new File("path/to/source/file");
File destination = new File("C:/Users/Victor/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/versions/1.7.10-OptiFine_HD_U_D6/1.7.10-OptiFine_HD_U_D6.jar");
try {
    Files.copy(source.toPath(), destination.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: "The dialog that says that the file already exists is simply a warning by Eclipse so you don't overwrite an already existing/the wrong file by accident; it has nothing to do with the operating system locking the file."
 
Hum... Eclipse lets me overwrite the file (I will give you somes screenshots) This the .jar that minecraft is using when it is running prntscr.com/ews8fo When I export an another .jar at the same location, Eclipse overwrite the file http://prntscr.com/ewsa5k As you can see, the .jar has changed but Minecraft is running http://prntscr.com/ewsaex

So How I could do this ?

Comment: The point is: **you can not do this at all**. You can change a JAR after Java has already loaded it, but once the JAR has been loaded, it would not be loaded again, so no changes would occur after the mod has been loaded.

Comment: That's what I want :) (= to change the JAR after Minecraft has loaded it, whitout applying the changes of the new jar and without loaded Minecraft again) So how can I do this ? (without using Eclipse)

Comment: I have an error (this is my code https://hastebin.com/ajoqatayoc.php, the error: https://hastebin.com/oyexikemac.css the line 16 is http://prntscr.com/ewwhno)

Comment: @D.Dreko my bad; `Files.copy(source.toPath(), destination.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);` should work though.

Comment: I have an error https://hastebin.com/huluketude.tex (I translated the error to English), the code https://hastebin.com/abubuwodaq.php, the line 17 is http://prntscr.com/ex3amv This code works when Minecraft is not running but not when Minecraft is running :/